# handling non-ascii logins when accessing RESTful django from iOS with http auth

Tags: ios, django, http-authentication

I have the following architecture: iOS client uses NSURLConnection with `willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge` to auth against Django-rest-framework based REST service. It works fine when login is ascii only, but when I use non-ascii letters, it even does not send `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` !

That is probably because RFC does not cover non-ascii chars in HTTP basic auth.

What is the best approach to solve it? Will digest auth help?

I can't encode login to url, since I do not want it to be displayed in server logs. And I also want to stay with `willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge`.

PS: I can use form-based auth or json-based on Django side (by implementing `BaseAuthentication`) but on iOS I will need to create `NSURLAuthenticationChallenge` which seems to be a big deal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you would be out of luck with both HTTP Basic & Digest authentication, it's only ASCII characters and there's simply no way to get around that.

However, because you're controlling the backend then you can use this trick: encode both the username and password in base64 on the iOS side like this:

```
NSData *usernameData = [username dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *usernameBase64 = [usernameData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

Then create your `NSURLCredential` with the encoded strings. Since HTTP Basic Authentication already encodes the credentials in base64, by doing this you will be encoding the credentials **twice** before sending them to the server.

Now on the DRF side, create a subclass of [`BasicAuthentication`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authentication.py#L55) and call it `Base64BasicAuthentication` for instance. Override `authenticate_credentials` like this:

```
def authenticate_credentials(self, userid, password):
    userid = base64.b64decode(userid)
    password = base64.b64decode(password)
    return super(Base64BasicAuthentication, self).authenticate_credentials(userid, password)
```

And then just use the `Base64BasicAuthentication` as your default auth class in Django REST Framework. It's a bit of a hack, but it should do the job.